# What curve is bell shaped in the normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The normal distribution is characterized by the bell shaped curve.

> My question is that which curve is bell shaped in the normal distribution? Is it the frequency histogram, the relative frequency curve, or the PDF that is bell shaped?

Comment: The density function is bell shaped

Comment: Then why I do see that it is the frequency histogram in some places?

Comment: From Wikipedia : "Histograms give a rough sense of the density of the underlying distribution of the data."

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#:~:text=Histograms%20give%20a%20rough%20sense,is%20always%20normalized%20to%201.

Comment: Thanks. What about the relative frequency curve?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Answer (score 0):

The normal distribution is continuous - it can take any value in the real numbers. Any value it takes has a zero probability of being exactly repeated - frequencies will be 0 or 1. So it has a probability density function, not a freqency curve.

A frequency histogram represents discrete values which may occur more than once. That might be for a discrete distribution (e.g. the Binomial) which is approximately normal, or for sample data from a normal distribution that has been grouped into ranges giving frequencies greater than 1. So when you see a freqency histogram in the classic bell shape, you're seeing something that approximates to, or derives from, a normal distribution.